# ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initailized

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

The error with ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized is giving me a fit.  I think I have it set up right. I will show you how I create the mssql connection and then what I am requesting, and the class I created to read/write and open/close the connection. (Three different parts of the app but I just lumped them together so you could see the actual logic flow I hope.)

What am I missing, or where am I supposed to put the connection? Example? I appreciate the help!

Here is the using statement I start with:

```
using (MSSQL mssqldb = new MSSQL(Constants.msSqlServer, Constants.msSqlDb, Constants.msSqlUid, Constants.msSqlPswd))
```

Here is where I say "Hey, get me my data using my `MSSQL` class"

```
using (var results = mssqldb.Read("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AlertLog ORDER BY AlarmID DESC"))
{
    results.Read();
    legacyAlert = Int32.Parse(results["AlarmId"].ToString().Trim());
}
```

Here is the MSSQL class

```
class MSSQL : IDisposable
{
    public MSSQL(string server, string database, string uid, string pswd)
    {
        string msSqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";user id=" + uid + ";password=" + pswd;

        SqlConnection msqlConnection = new SqlConnection(msSqlConnectionString);
        msqlConnection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("MS SQL OPEN!");
    }

    public void Write(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, msqlConnection))
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public SqlDataReader Read(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, msqlConnection))
        return myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try {
            msqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("MS SQL Error - Closing Database");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        msqlConnection.Dispose();
    }

    private SqlConnection msqlConnection;
}
```

Comment: A bit off-base, but you shouldn't create a single connection to the server like that. When you're done with the connection, it should be disposed of.

Comment: I had thought about that, but I use it everywhere in the app in multiple threads, so I decided to use it from the top.  I understand what you are saying, but I thought it would save me multiple connection issues.

Comment: This sounds like all those "I thought string concatenation would save me multiple parameterization issues..." arguments that happen *before* a web site gets hacked with SQL injection...

Comment: This is getting off topic, there is a suggestion to an answer below, but I don't understand it.  If anyone could possibly show me an example of what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msqlConnection` is null.

Your constructor creates a local variable named `msqlConnection`, but does not assign to the field.

Comment: Still learning programming, so please excuse my ignorance. I used exactly the same way for a mysql connection and that works, but i don't understand the assign to the field part that you mean.

Comment: OK, a big DUH... thanks I figured it out after it was staring me in the face for a few minutes.